# Change Core Data entity name with Lightweight migration?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, refactoring, migration

Is there a way to change the name of a Core Data entity name while still using "Automatic Lightweight Migration" on iOS?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the destination model, set the renaming identifier to the name of the entity in the source model.

In Xcode 3, the renaming identifier is in the User Info pane of the Detail Pane, below the version hash modifier.

In Xcode 4, it's in the right hand (Utilities) below Versioning.