# Core data versioning and migration

Tags: iphone, core-data, core-data-migration

I have the older version of the core data model of the released app. Now, in the next version of the app, I am migrating the core data model to new model. Is there a way to get the attribute values from the old model before actually migrating to the new version of the model or is there possibly a way to know if the migration is to be occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you migrate, Core Data actually moves existing values for you. If you're doing a relatively simple migration, such as adding or removing some properties, Core Data does its best to make the move as seamless as possible. In many cases, you won't need to make any changes other than set your new model. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413669/core-data-versioning-manually/6414109#6414109) for more.

Comment: +1 Migration is actually the process of rewriting an existing persistent store to the new structure dictated by the newer version of the data model.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

To get the attribute values from the old model you'll need to create custom entity migration policies (`NSEntityMigrationPolicy` subclasses). Then in `-createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance:entityMapping:manager:error:` you'll receive source instance, and it is completely up to you how to create destination instances from source instances.

There is a method to check if a given store is compatible with store coordinator model: `-[NSManagedObjectModel isConfiguration:compatibleWithStoreMetadata:]`.